# Are antisemitic conspiracy theories against policy?

Tags: discussion, moderation, flagging

I flagged [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3009/why-do-people-consider-israel-to-be-an-apartheid-country/3077#3077) as "rude or abusive". The flag reason states:

> A reasonable person would find this content [inappropriate for respectful discourse](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

The linked policy states:

> Bigotry of any kind. Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At all. (Those are just a few examples; when in doubt, just don't.)

The answer in question states this:

> [...] while Jews support these racial nationalistic policies in Israel
>   they work for the opposite in Europe and America, Such as supporting
>   massive non European immigration into Europe and promoting
>   European/White women dating Africans Arabs etc on TV/Films they make,
>   check out http://www.europeandailynews.org/ They do a great job
>   covering the racism and crime against White European people

This is pretty obviously antisemitic and racist.

Still, the flag was declined:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

But I did not flag the post because it was inaccurate (although it obviously is), I flagged it because I think that it is against policy.

So my questions is:

- Does the policy apply here, and are antisemitic conspiracy theories against the policy[*], and should thus be flagged and deleted?

<sub>[*] When provided without context. I'm of course not objecting to questions talking about antisemitic conspiracy theories such as [this one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8416/what-is-the-fascist-argument-for-marxism-being-a-jewish-conspiracy), I'm objecting to answers spreading antisemitic conspiracy theories.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

When I quickly looked through the answer, the part that stood out to me the most was the part about Israel, and the rest seemed like typical answer fluff.

Since the part about Jews being socially liberal in Europe and America, was what you found offensive, and since it is off topic, I've now removed that part of the answer.

The part about Isreal, however, truly was about Israel, and it actually did a pretty good job of avoiding inflammatory language.

All that's left that's wrong with that part is the correctness of it, and as the built-in flag declining reason says, you shouldn't flag answers for being incorrect.  You should down vote them instead.

The reason why this is the policy is so the mods aren't the deciders of correctness.

Comment: It wasn't just that Jews are supposedly socially liberal, it was about Jews controlling the media (`on TV/Films they [the Jews] make`) to bring about a white genocide (this is only implied, but pretty clear from context: `[The Jews support] massive non European immigration`, `[The Jews promote] European/White women dating Africans Arabs`, `[The Jews cover up] racism and crime against White European people`), which isn't just answer fluff, but classic antisemtitism.

Comment: This answer is fine now (it's still wrong, but that is indeed what voting is for), but I think it would still be great to have an answer for the more general question.For example, the other answer by that user is completely on-topic, but also contains language that I think is likely to alienate individuals based on race (`In Norway 100% of all rapes are committed by non European immigrants against Norwegians`). So it would be nice to have a reference post so people know how and when the policy applies here.

Comment: "Since the part about Jews being socially liberal in Europe and America" - that's a rather interesting way of characterising that content. "was what you found offensive" - as opposed to it *actually* being offensive?