# Engaging in holocaust denial is not acceptable behaviour

Tags: discussion

I flagged the holocaust-denying post [Man who claimed to have escaped Auschwitz admits he lied for years](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11437/man-who-claimed-to-have-escaped-auschwitz-admits-he-lied-for-years) as offensive. The flag was declined, with the message

> declined - This is a Politics Q&A site. We should be able to discuss the Holocaust without getting so easily offended.

There's plenty of other sites on the internet which allow people to engage in holocaust denial, but there's no need for this garbage and hate speech on Stack Exchange. We're not an "anything goes" website, and we don't claim to be one. It's one where people post factual questions and get factual answers. It's not for posting absolute nonsense as fact, let alone when it's hate speech.

Related question: [Are antisemitic conspiracy theories against policy?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2597/are-antisemitic-conspiracy-theories-against-policy)

Comment: Please explain how exactly that question is a "holocaust-denying post". Does the mere suggestion that some of the holocaust stories may need to be a bit more thoroughly investigated count as "posting absolute nonsense as fact" and "hate speech" in your book?

Comment: @Yannis Well, he is questioning the very concept of "Holocaust denial" being a bad thing.

Comment: @SamIam In the comments. However, it was the question that was flagged, not the comments.

Comment: @Yannis the comment proved what I suspected about the question.

Comment: Flagging based on suspicions instead of actual evidence can be risky @AndrewGrimm.

Comment: @Yannis many holocaust deniers try to pretend they're not holocaust deniers.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm This is true, but I don't see how is relevant to this discussion. You flagged a question. Nothing in the question's text justified the flag (at the time I saw it), and I declined it. Your suspicions (which I happened to share to a degree) are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time you flagged the question, there was nothing in its text that I would count as "holocaust-denying", "hate speech" or "absolute nonsense as fact".

True, it wasn't a stellar question, and I won't deny that it smelt funny. However, the offensive flag carries a certain weight and shouldn't be used without concrete evidence to back it up.

I think your vote to close was enough in this case.