# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion

Recently, I posted an answer which was deleted for 'wrongthink'. For those of you who have not read it, here is a [screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYfYk.jpg) of the now deleted answer.

The rationale given is that my answer had "white supremacist" propaganda. Yet I do not believe this is the case. Many mainstream conservatives are also aware of the heinous anti-white sentiment/violence in South Africa, the most mainstream of whom is sitting in the Oval Office. Many mainstream conservatives are also aware of the fact that American blacks commit disproportionately more crime, which was a relevant point in my answer. See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KIpcxy9M1pw) video by conservative YouTuber Sargon of Akkad, who is opposed to the alt-right.

Perhaps the issue was with a source I cited, American Renaissance. This is supposedly "white supremacist". Yet this is again inaccurate. It is not "white supremacist". It is "white nationalist". This is what the organization describes itself as. It is indeed described as "white supremacist" by the mainstream corporate media, but the mainstream corporate media is itself anti-white (think Sarah Jeong), so it is not a reliable arbiter on these matters. By siding with the mainstream, leftist corporate media on these questions, the moderators of this website are letting it be known that the only political views this site finds acceptable are those which far-left news corporations deem acceptable.

The articles I cited from American Renaissance were cogent, well-argued and cited reliable primary sources. The only reason they were unacceptable is because they constituted "wrongthink". To be blunt, it's because because they hurt the feelings of the moderators. Apparently, there is only one "acceptable" opinion on the white South African question, and any answers deviating from that "acceptable" opinion are deleted.

This is not consistent with politics.SE being an open platform for genuine intellectual discussion. If you don't like my answer, or the sources my answer cites, why not debate? Why censor? A very anti-intellectual attitude.

I mean, imagine if a conservative moderator decided to ban all answers citing CNN or NYT, because he regarded such organizations as being "fake news propaganda". Ludicrous, right?

> If liberty means anything at all, it means the right to tell people what they do not want to hear.
>
> -George Orwell

Comment: Related https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3585/why-were-answers-deleted-at-a-question-addressing-south-africa-and-white-farmer. Posted that question before reading this question.

Comment: Regardless of source, your answer still should have been deleted as it did not answer the question, your rhetoric just quickened the deletion. US national interest is decided by those elected to further US national interest, that's what representative democracy is all about. US national interest is not decided by strangers on the internet, therefore your *opinion* was not an *answer*, right or wrong as it may be - and this is a Q&A site, not an opinion site. An answer would contain some official statement of why an action was taken by someone whose job it is to represent US national interest

Answer (score -15, accepted):

Unfortunately, content at SE sites is frequently deleted or [defaced](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3790/remove-add-citations-label-from-answer) by vote of users and moderators.

The content of your answer, including the comments, and the answer of [rs.29](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/15889/rs-29) is neither "offensive" nor "rude" within the context of political discourse.

It is highly unlikely that your answer or the answer of user rs.29 will be un-deleted. From perspective here, the answers should not have been deleted in the first instance.

Mature political discourse requires parties and interests having widely differing views to sit at the same table and discuss the matters at hand. Not to arbitrarily stifle dissent or perspectives that do not fit in to some pseudo mold.

Whether one agrees or disagrees with the content is that individuals' choice. The perspectives themselves are valuable.

The only action that this user can take is to remind users of the importance of not stifling political dissent, which perhaps users here will review and come to the realization that deleting content is akin to the establishment of a Stack Exchange [Stasi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stasi), whereby in the fervent desire to delete content of users SE becomes an instrument of policies and actions which it purports to abhor. See a quote attributed to [Voltaire](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Voltaire#Quotes)

> - I disapprove of what you say, but I will defend to the death your right to say it.
>
>   - Though these words are regularly attributed to Voltaire, they were first used by [Evelyn Beatrice Hall](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Evelyn_Beatrice_Hall), writing under the pseudonym
>       of Stephen G Tallentyre in *The Friends of Voltaire* (1906), as a
>       summation of Voltaire's beliefs on freedom of thought and
>       expression.[[13]](http://books.google.it/books?id=j3kGAQAAIAAJ&q=%22I%20disapprove%20of%20what%20you%20say,%20but%20I%20will%20defend%20to%20the%20death%20your%20right%20to%20say%20it%22%20intitle:%22The%20Friends%20of%20Voltaire%22&dq=%22I%20disapprove%20of%20what%20you%20say,%20but%20I%20will%20defend%20to%20the%20death%20your%20right%20to%20say%20it%22%20intitle:%22The%20Friends%20of%20Voltaire%22&hl=it&ei=6J3uTbDYKcLX8gOnkLGTBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA)
>   - Another possible source for the quote was proposed by Norbert Guterman, editor of "A Book of French Quotations," who noted a letter
>       to M. le Riche (6 February 1770) in which Voltaire is quoted as
>       saying: "Monsieur l'abbé, I detest what you write, but I would give my
>       life to make it possible for you to continue to write" ("Monsieur
>       l'abbé, je déteste ce que vous écrivez, mais je donnerai ma vie pour
>       que vous puissiez continuer à écrire"). This remark, however, does not
>       appear in the letter.

[Some Elementary Comments on The Rights of Freedom of Expression](https://chomsky.info/19801011/) by Noam Chomsky

> I made it explicit that I would not discuss Faurisson's work, having
>   only limited familiarity with it (and, frankly, little interest in
>   it). Rather, I restricted myself to the civil-liberties issues and the
>   implications of the fact that it was even necessary to recall
>   Voltaire's famous words in a letter to M. le Riche: "I detest what you
>   write, but I would give my life to make it possible for you to
>   continue to write." [...] Many writers find it scandalous that I
>   should support the right of free expression for Faurisson without
>   carefully analyzing his work, a strange doctrine which, if adopted,
>   would effectively block defense of civil rights for unpopular views.
>   [...]
>
> It seems to me something of a scandal that it is even necessary to
>   debate these issues two centuries after Voltaire defended the right of
>   free expression for views he detested. It is a poor service to the
>   memory of the victims of the holocaust to adopt a central doctrine of
>   their murderers.
>
> Let me add a final remark about Faurisson’s alleged “anti-Semitism.”
>   Note first that even if Faurisson were to be a rabid anti-Semite and
>   fanatic pro-Nazi — such charges have been presented to me in private
>   correspondence that it would be improper to cite in detail here — this
>   would have no bearing whatsoever on the legitimacy of the defense of
>   his civil rights. On the contrary, it would make it all the more
>   imperative to defend them since, once again, it has been a truism for
>   years, indeed centuries, that it is precisely in the case of
>   horrendous ideas that the right of free expression must be most
>   vigorously defended; it is easy enough to defend free expression for
>   those who require no such defense. Putting this central issue aside,
>   is it true that Faurisson is an anti-Semite or a neo-Nazi? As noted
>   earlier, I do not know his work very well. But from what I have read —
>   largely as a result of the nature of the attacks on him — I find no
>   evidence to support either conclusion. Nor do I find credible evidence
>   in the material that I have read concerning him, either in the public
>   record or in private correspondence. As far as I can determine, he is
>   a relatively apolitical liberal of some sort. In support of the charge
>   of anti-Semitism, I have been informed that Faurisson is remembered by
>   some schoolmates as having expressed anti-Semitic sentiments in the
>   1940s, and as having written a letter that some interpret as having
>   anti-Semitic implications at the time of the Algerian war. I am a
>   little surprised that serious people should put such charges forth —
>   even in private — as a sufficient basis for castigating someone as a
>   long-time and well-known anti-Semitic. I am aware of nothing in the
>   public record to support such charges. I will not pursue the exercise,
>   but suppose we were to apply similar standards to others, asking, for
>   example, what their attitude was towards the French war in Indochina,
>   or to Stalinism, decades ago. Perhaps no more need be said.

Answer (score 10):

In most cases, a debate is preferable to outright deletion.

However, that answer is hardly the first time your behaviour has caused concern. In fact, you have posted more than several outright racist comments & posts. The community has tried several times, through comments, Meta, moderator messages and suspensions to help you understand that racism will not be tolerated on this site. To this, you've often responded with [racial slurs and personal attacks](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3254/do-we-really-want-to-tolerate-personal-attacks-and-antisemitism-here). At one point, you've even had the audacity to add [antisemitic remarks in your profile page](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3281/why-was-my-profile-modified).

Is it really that surprising that people aren't interested in debating with you anymore?

Comment: This recent answer did not contain any "slurs" or otherwise offensive remarks.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122, that's what we call *reputation*. While generally, people at SE care about "posts, not users", nothing prevents them from remembering *your* past actions and from being more vigilant about *your* posts. Good news is that, today must be a suitable moment to start rebuilding one's good name.

Comment: @bytebuster Online reputation is not the most important thing to me. If people here dislike me, that's understandable—ultimately, you cannot please everyone. Nevertheless, as a matter of _policy_, I don't think it's appropriate for moderators to be deleting posts based on past grudges or politically incorrect views. You can dislike someone without actively trying to censor them.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Your answer makes a lot of very strong claims. It does, however, very little to back up those claims. To make matters worse, the little that it does is just a link to a ...controversial source. You have been asked in comments to substantiate the claims in your answer. A random link is not enough. If you insist at using the source, at the very least quote the exact portion of the article that backs up your claim. Also, consider using additional sources. If your points are as uncontroversial and well known as you seem to think, then this should be easy.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Racism is not a "politically incorrect view".

Answer (score 8):

I voted your answer as "rude and abusive" because you were using white supremacist trash to try and justify your argument, regardless of what the author tries to call it, and that kind of drivel has no place on this site. And based off your comments on https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/33180/10183, you have learned nothing from your previous meta conversations.

Feel free to be upset and confused about it, I'll happily take responsibility for any discomfort caused. And just so we're clear: I'll personally be extra careful to keep an eye on you and flag any additional attempts at spreading hateful messages going forward, and I don't feel the least bit guilty saying I sincerely hope you either change your posting habits or get removed forcefully from this site.

Comment: _"because you were using white supremacist .. to try and justify your argument"_ Users still have a right to their own perspective. One could argue that the United States itself is a white supremacist organization, though questions and answer concerning U.S. policy are posted every day at this site. If you are going to delete answers simply because you do not agree with their views you might as well write to the "Twitter" service to delete all of the "tweets" of the current U.S. President. See [Faurisson affair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faurisson_affair)

Comment: @guest271314 "Users still have a right to their own perspective." Maybe (though remember perspectives *can* be wrong), but here on Stack Exchange we have *standards*. And users have the responsibility to uphold those standards, otherwise Stack Exchange has the *right* to revoke that users *privileges*.

Comment: [Comments archived](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82581/discussion-on-answer-by-ggmg-why-was-my-answer-deleted). If you wish to continue the discussion on free speech, political discourse and Stack Exchange, please do it in chat.