# Why were answers deleted at a question addressing South Africa and "white farmers"?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

See the [Faurisson affair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faurisson_affair)

> I made it explicit that I would not discuss Faurisson's work, having
>   only limited familiarity with it (and, frankly, little interest in
>   it). **Rather, I restricted myself to the civil-liberties issues and the
>   implications of the fact that it was even necessary to recall
>   Voltaire's famous words in a letter to M. le Riche: "I detest what you
>   write, but I would give my life to make it possible for you to
>   continue to write."** [...] Many writers find it scandalous that I
>   should support the right of free expression for Faurisson without
>   carefully analyzing his work, a strange doctrine which, if adopted,
>   would effectively block defense of civil rights for unpopular views.
>   [...] (emphasis added)

The answers of users MathematicsStudent1122 and rs.29 are representations of those users' perspectives regarding the matter of "the South Africa land and farm seizures and expropriations and large scale killing of farmers" and "South African Government is now seizing land from white farmers."

Why were the answers of users [MathematicsStudent1122](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/5904/mathematicsstudent1122) and [rs.29](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/15889/rs-29) deleted at [What national interest does the U.S. have in "the South Africa land and farm seizures and expropriations"?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/33172/what-national-interest-does-the-u-s-have-in-the-south-africa-land-and-farm-sei)

Comment: The answers detail and reflect the sentiment of the U.S. President. They should not have been deleted, and should be immediately un-deleted, no matter how unpopular they might be. "down" vote if you decide, but deleting the answers is outright censorship. If you cannot handle dissenting perspectives either way, then stop reading the answer instead of stifling dissent by deleting the answers.

Comment: Given the sheer number of times you come into Meta to complain about things being deleted, I don't think the moderators are stifling *anything* by deleting answers.

Comment: @F1Krazy The evidence supports the fact that moderators are deleting far too much content - on a political board. Simply because users' emotions get inflamed is not reason for stifling political dissent. Adults are able to make their own decisions about the content, without some would-be "big brother" deleting content which conveys those users' perspectives. There is no "complain" involved. Am pointed out objectively incorrect and wrong behaviour that should be corrected. Those users' perspectives are valuable in spite of people not agreeing with them.

Comment: Partial duplicate: [Why was my answer deleted?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3582/why-was-my-answer-deleted)

Comment: US national interest is decided by those elected to further US national interest, that's what representative democracy is all about. US national interest is not decided by strangers on the internet, therefore their *opinions* were not *answers*, right or wrong as they may be - and this is a Q&A site, not an opinion site. An answer would contain some official statement of why an action was taken by someone whose job it is to represent US national interest

Comment: @Gramatik Your opinion of what national interest is and who represents that interest at all times is simply inaccurate. The President of the United States at all times represents the interests of the United States, in all statements and actions, as the individual who holds that Office, the Executive Branch of Government, is acting in their official capacity at all times when holding that Office. You are not the individual who decides what is contained in an answer. The individual who decides to answer a question decides what content is included in their answer.

Comment: @guest271314 I'm aware the president represents those interests, that's what I was saying. That a stranger on the internet does cannot definitively say "this is the US national interest in X", only the executive branch. Therefore these speculative "answers" do not constitute an acceptable answer as defined by this site. Again, this is a Q&A site, not an opinion site.

Answer (score 10):

There are at least two more answers on that question that should be deleted or heavily edited, for the simple fact that they *do not attempt to answer the question* or spend far more time editorializing or debating your sources than in addressing your question. Frankly, you've not gotten a very good set of answers there yet, and if I was an active member of this site I'd be pretty concerned about that.

This isn't a discussion board; [it is imperative that answers answer the question asked](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Failing to do this - or using answers as a soapbox for one's opinion without paying more than lip service to the existence of a question to be answered - is and will always be grounds for removal. That the answers removed were divisive and polemical in addition to their irrelevance only hastens their removal.

Part of the problem here might be that your original question butchered the Reuters quote, clipping two-thirds of a sentence from the middle of a paragraph. I assume the intent of that quote was to provide a statement of fact on the South African situation from a relatively neutral party; I'm afraid though that it became almost incoherent due to the redactions.

I've expanded that quote to the entirety of the two relevant paragraphs, and also added [some attribution](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) - please be careful in the future when using others' words that you don't inadvertently misrepresent what they were trying to say.

Comment: The answers did answer the question. Stop censoring and deleting content. You accomplish nothing except making SE into Stasi SE.

Comment: I read them, @guest271314. I also read your question. If you meant to ask something other than what you did, I suggest you post a new question.

Comment: Your last sentence makes no sense. The deleted answers presented those users political perspective of why the U.S. has a national interest in South Africa. The deletion of the answers was an indication of immature political understanding of real-world politics where somehow deleting an answer is viewed as dismissal of the political opinion into oblivion. Those users' political perspective is valuable and should not have been deleted in the first place. it is a ridiculous action that has no merit other than bias. That is not how real politics works. There was no misrepresentation of anything.

Comment: One person's opinions don't constitute a U.S. national interest. There are hundreds of millions of individuals in this country and many times more perspectives on just about anything; we have a system of government that seeks to represent some cross-section of that, but does not purport to endorse anything and everything a citizen might say or think. To conflate the ideas of an individual or subgroup with national interest is to observe a bee and call it a swarm.

Comment: The individuals' answered detailing their perspective of the national interest of the U.S. in South Africa, which, again, is valuable. Do not have to _agree_ with their perspective to still stand for the right of those persons or groups to state what their perspective is. Those answers provided insight into the beliefs and concerns of a large enough segment of the population that the U.S. President saw fit to make the cause celebre a national issue by publishing their official statement to the world. The statement was made on behalf of the views posted in the answers. That is valuable content.

Comment: Do you plan to expand this to a nation-wide poll, @guest? To interrogate the elected officials and civil servants as to the interests they serve? "National interest" is a term with a history and a meaning, not a euphemism for "some folks' idle chit-chat"; if you're going to ask for something specific, you should ensure that you get what you ask for. There are many sites on the Internet where you can find opinions and non-answers to any question you may wish to pose; there's no need to use this one if you prefer to listen to the ramblings of the bored than to gain assistance.

Comment: _""National interest" is a term with a history and a meaning"_ Really? See the link to the description of the usage of "national interest" at https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/33175/21216. What meaning are you applying to the term? You simply place an un-earned lofty opinion on your own opinion of what SE is. You do a dis-service to your own platform by the censorship and defacing of answers that you engage in. It solves nothing besides limiting the scope of your content to the same homogeneous views recycled and regurgitated ad infinitum. Yes, might start own platform.

Comment: Your answer is no different than the deleted answers' content: At least they were direct. Your view is narrow and you are fine with that. When you could be far more inclusive. However, you cater to emotion rather than stepping back and allowing the content to level itself out. Again, akin to the Stasi always being "right" because the Stasi controls the switchboard. Though, when you want to fly _your_ political flag you delete nothing and argue that that is fine https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342940. Essentially hypocritical conduct.

Comment: Proof of the hypocrisy at SE: _"After all the mess caused by changing the logo just because Joel is homosexual. ..Surprisingly, various Stack Overflow employees kept abusing their binding votes to reopen the question against the will of the community. Basically, Joel violates the policies of the site because he is the CEO, and his team enforces his view. Some elected moderators disagreed with the reopening, but I guess they were too afraid that their powers would be revoked if they used their binding votes to close or lock."_ Yet you get on some would-be high horse here. Stop censoring content

Comment: I recommend, when looking for definitions, to [start with a dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/national%20interest) @guest. Not opinion pieces. That you'd argue the opposite does help me to understand your distress in this situation however. I recommend avoiding arbitrary opinions until you've done a bit of study on the topic you wish to learn about; this baseline knowledge helps a great deal in putting those opinions into context.

Comment: Still you are not being clear about your focus on the "national interest" portion of the question. Am well aware what "national interest" is and construction. It is different depending on whom is asked. It is made _self-evident_ by _official actions_. The _action_ of statements re South Africa and specifically "white farmers" makes it abundantly clear that the national interest of the U.S., as stated by its Commander-In-Chief is a white supremacist interest, which is consistent with the U.S.'s white supremacist origin, historical actions and policies. The deleted answers pointed to those facts

Comment: I didn't write your question, @guest. I don't know, nor particularly care why you asked for what you asked - I assume you had good reason for it. If you're now arguing that you asked for something with no use for it nor even interest in getting what you asked for... Then you were dishonest and wasted a fair few people's time - if this is the case, I kindly ask that you do not waste any more of mine.

Comment: What are you talking about? Your last comment makes no sense. The original question is clear. This meta question specifically asks why the answers were deleted. If you have an issue interpreting the original question that is your failure, not any error or omission at the original question. Perhaps you are simply incapable of understanding the original question, or the importance of not censoring content. You can simply read another question if your understanding does not allow you to understand the question, or you simply don't like the question. Those are your own limitations.

Comment: By the way, while you are here, can you individually or kindly direct someone in your organization to remove the defacing, utterly meritless label at this answer https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3790/remove-add-citations-label-from-answer? The label is prima facie evidence of "deceptive practices" by your organization, as all citations are included in the answer.

Comment: You asked for relevance of a statement to the US national interest, @guest. I would assume, then, that you wanted an answer that explained how the statement related to the US national interest, not a discussion on the subjectiveness of "national interest" as a concept. If I ask you for the timezone in Sydney, I expect "UTC+10" not a debate over the arbitrariness or historical unfairness of time. So which is it? Did you ask for something you didn't want, or are you upset that you lost something you don't need?

Comment: Am not "upset" about anything. Posted this meta question specifically to defend the right of users' to post their political perspectives on this political board without dissent being stifled. Not sure why you keep referring to "national interest"? The point of this meta question is to get the deleted answers un-deleted. Whether one agrees or disagrees with the content of the answers is irrelevant. The answers should not have been deleted in the first place. This meta question is about the principles of freedom of expression, see https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3587/21216

Comment: Then there's your source of confusion, @guest: no one has the right to post their political perspectives here; that's simply not what this place is for. I recommend you start with the tour: https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: _"This meta question is about the **principles of freedom of expression**"_ not "right". You are evidently simply incapable of gathering that deletion of the answers is the same, if not more horrendous, than any content in the answers themselves. SE claims that this is a politics board, though it evidently is not. Political discourse comprises all political content, not just homosexual content because an executive of the corporation promotes their homosexual political agenda on SE. At least tried to convey reason here. That is all that can do.

Comment: Again, I *really* think you should [read the tour](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour). You're making a lot of claims about this site that the site doesn't make for itself.

Comment: Read the link. The answers answered the question. Delete the comments attached to the answers if you so choose. Deleting the answers is reprehensible and void of all merit.

Comment: [It's a short tour](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour); take you maybe 5 minutes, way less time than you've already invested in this doomed conversation. If you're still feeling energetic, [there's a ton of good stuff in the help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) too.

Comment: Just said read the tour. Nothing in that tour states that the deleted answers did not answer the question. Am never not energetic. Especially when it comes to freedom of expression and suppression of that expression.

Comment: Tour tells you what the site is for, and what's on-topic here. Here, [read it again](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour), you'll see.

Comment: The answers are on-topic. The tour does not state that users have to agree with the content of the answer. "down" votes suffice to communicate the view of those users' who "down" vote. Deletion of the answers is ridiculous. Have you bothered to read this users' linked answer?

Comment: Is it the animation? I understand that can be distracting; look, [just search the page](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour) for the text "Get answers to practical, detailed questions" - it'll take you right to the section. Give it a sec for the animations to finish, and it's all right there.

Comment: Yes, the answers satisfy the requirements listed at the linked page. The tour does not state that users' _have_ to **agree** with the premises or content of the answer.

Comment: Ok, I apologize, I forget sometimes how many years I've been staring at this stuff; take all the time you need & study it closely. Every single bit of text on that page is important, and if you overlook it you'll come away with a bad idea of what we're doing here - as you did and have. Here's the link again, for convenience: https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: The second link does not change the analysis of the deletion of the answers. The answers provided the valuable political perspective and **answers** of those users to the original question.

Comment: Hi again, @guest - I've contacted you privately with a list of reading material that we'd all consider essential for understanding the nature of these sites. Please study it before continuing here. Thanks!

Comment: Just as a point of order, if your edit had come through the suggested edits queue, I would have voted to reject it as Attempt to Reply.  In particular, the second paragraph has no place in the question.  It only makes sense if you are arguing that the premise of the question is false.  I submit that an answer would be a much better way to make that clarification, as then you could explain why you think that the alleged seizures were actually part of that program and not separate.  Something that an edit does not allow.

Comment: Note:  I understand that to you, you were just correcting a quote.  But to an external observer, what you actually did is change the question.  Part of it I can even see as borderline, although it's a bit of non sequitur.  Even if the rate has been falling, that refutes something that isn't in the question itself.  But the part about the separate program to buy and give property doesn't address whether there is also a program to seize and give.  I don't want to argue; you aren't going to convince me.  I fundamentally disagree with that kind of edit.  They don't work on partisan subjects.

Comment: "Respect the original author's intent" is the rule when editing, @Brythan; I've come to have doubts as to that intent in the 20-some comments preceding this, but at the time of the edit I had nothing but the question itself to go on - and I did not alter the question being asked at all.

Comment: However partisan the question might be, the quote I altered referenced a major wire service and I would not default to assuming a partisan slant there - so my assumption as to the author's intent in using the quote was as I stated above: a statement of fact as a baseline for interpreting the other quotes. Both paragraphs serve that purpose, which is also the purpose the served in the article being quoted. Meta: if you don't want to argue, then don't leave two back-to-back comments; the effort betrays your intent. Happy to take this to a new meta discussion if you wish to not argue further...

Comment: @Shog9: contrary to what you might have learned in a dictionary, "national interest" is a matter of opinion; quoting from the Wikipedia page (an example) "With hegemonic stability theory, the concept of the U.S. national interest was expanded to include the maintenance of open sea lanes and the maintenance and expansion of free trade." Clearly the US public may not quite dig the latter now, since they elected Trump who has a different view on trade. If we just use his slogan, national interest is now "fair trade".

Comment: @Shog9: You can read more definitions of the notion and examples at https://prog.lmu.edu.ng/colleges_CMS/document/books/National%20Interest%20&%20International%20Interest,%20Part%201.pdf Some are dull and obvious like including teritorial intergrity and some more "spicy" including racial criteria (surely applied by some countries, at least in the past).

Comment: @Shog9: Fun document for you to read on US' [proposed] interests (found via previous link): https://www.belfercenter.org/sites/default/files/legacy/files/amernatinter.pdf It ranks the prevention of genocide and supressing terrorism as equally important (on the 2nd tier of ineterest, "extremely important"). And we all know how many US troops went to Rwanda.

Comment: And amusingly (for me) some argued for another similar commission some 12 years later: https://doi.org/10.1080/23258020.2013.864884

Comment: And the Harvard generator of national interest (papers) didn't stop there https://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/20057953/Russia-and-US-NI_final-web.pdf "The United States should be prepared to launch a genuine and substantive dialogue first
with its NATO allies and then with Russia about a new inclusive European security system
that would give Russia a meaningful voice and that would include an effective rapid
response mechanism of conflict prevention, interdiction and resolution.
" That was in 2011.

Comment: I lived through the '80s, @Fizz - I'm well aware of how easily "national interest" can be tossed around as justification. But the problem with glibly defining it as "opinion" is twofold... Some folks' opinions matter a lot more than others (if Bob from Piscataway thinks it's in our national interest to fund more corn subsidies that doesn't quite rate the way Sonny Perdue's opinion does). But more importantly: it makes the answer to any question like guest's trite: "it's in our national interest because Trump believes it is". In practice, *actionable* opinions have to have some justification.

Answer (score 6):

The [code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) is pretty explicit:

> We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion — and those are just a few examples. When in doubt, just don’t."

Stack Exchange deciding that they will not be a forum for this sort of hate is not censorship. If someone wants to spread white supremacist propaganda, they are free to create their own website, or to do so on existing sites like stormfront or 4chan.

Additionally, Stack Exchange isn't a "board". It's a Q&A website. "Users' perspectives" aren't really what any Stack Exchange site is looking for; instead, substantiated posts that answer the question are what this site is about. Some answers may fall short of that, and that isn't always a reason to delete them, but when some users decide to almost exclusively use this site to spread their hateful propaganda, then something is clearly going wrong; that just isn't what Stack Exchange is intended to be used for.

Comment: The entire history of the U.S. political machine is rife with content that would apparently "offend" or "alienate" people. It makes no sense to censor content and stifle dissent. The individuals will simply not go away. It is far more prudent to place all of the views on the table, discuss the matters in detail, then make decisions - individually.  One cannot know the difference between or find common ground with a SHARP, a Peckerwood, a Skin Head, "alt-right" or "white nationalist" without having discourse with each.

Comment: @guest271314 History being full of bad stuff is not a reason to continue doing bad stuff. It's better to learn from history (which nobody is talking about censoring) and not repeat past mistakes. Coincidentally SE policy is for preventing new mistakes.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara What you are missing in your analysis is that SE is making the same mistake; essentially being a SE Stasi - not allowing political dissent. Therefore people will never know the difference between a SHARP and a white nationalist if you do not sit down and listen to what they are saying. You certainly will not ever get to the point where you can find common ground after the yelling and screaming subsides - which is the goal: what is the common ground after the emotional responses have been stated. There is no "bad stuff"; it is just "stuff"; stop labeling content.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara It is possible that users at Politics SE are wholly incapable of mature political discourse, and are instead only capable of understanding their own ideas and excluding others ideas from even consideration. In this venue users can delete content. In the real world people cannot simply wish others to the corn field and abracadabra, the _other_ disappears. You have to deal with those same people every day in all human activities, thus you MUST understand where they are coming from - and the nuanced differences between what might appear to be _they are all the same_.

Comment: @guest271314 Why would anyone want to find common ground with white supremacists? But even if you do, this isn't the site for that. The difference between a SHARP and a white supremacist is pretty easy to find; I don't have to extensively talk with the later to find that difference. But if I do want that, this isn't the site for that.

Comment: I can use secondary sources to find out more about white supremacist thinking, I can visit their websites (instead of inviting them to every website that exists so that they can use it to further spread their propaganda), I can go out and find one, or I can ask a question about white supremacy here.

Comment: @tim Because the reality is there are class issues ongoing which have far greater actual practical importance than any fictitious "race" issues. The U.S. is a white supremacist organization, you might as well delete all references to the U.S. at Politics SE as well. People here are simply used to "delete" answer equating to the concept being gone forever. That is not the case in real politics. Other parties are not going anywhere, and alliances are formed between widely varying political groups and individuals for the greater good of the entire society.

Comment: @guest271314 There is a world of difference between talking about white supremacy and actively spreading white supremacy propaganda. Once you realize this you'll realize your straw man makes no sense.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Again, the United States is a white supremacist organization; conceived to be a white supremacist nation and remaining a white supremacist nation. There is no substantial difference from the views presented in the deleted answers from "Travel Ban" and "Zero Tolerance" policies of the U.S. U.S. propaganda _is_ white supremacist propaganda. Delete all questions and answers dealing with U.S. policy then you will be equally applying your posture. Else, you are picking and choosing between the same white supremacist propaganda. Its all the same.

Comment: @guest271314 So what if that's true? We can talk about the KKK without spreading white-supremacist propaganda. There lies the difference. You can talk about the KKK no problem, but you can't go on spreading their propaganda unless you clearly mark it as such. The user with the white-supremacy symbol of an avatar fell on the wrong side of that line.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara The United States flag is a white supremacist symbol. No different than the Confederate States of America national flag.

Comment: @guest271314 This is a bit off-topic, because the main points here are 1) Racism is not tolerated at SE 2) This site isn't about *doing* politics, but about asking and answering questions *about* politics. But anyways, I don't think that there is a main contradiction (class), and then secondary ones (race, gender, etc) which can be pushed aside.

Comment: @guest271314 And white supremacists *make* race an issue of practical importance. When white supremacists go out in the streets to murder people based on their ideas of race (or go into parliament to pass laws based on them), then race *is* an issue, whether you think that the concept is fictitious or not. But again, this is really about the two basic points about what is allowed here and what isn't, and what SE is meant to be and what it isn't meant to be. Both issues are network-wide issues and can't really be changed here (even if we wanted to).

Comment: @tim The answers were no more "racist" than any other content. Just honest and direct. Again, do not have to _agree_ with a political perspective to still defend the individuals' right to present their perspective. If you are stating that "racism" is not allowed, you might as well delete all questions and answers that deal with "race" - which is _arbitrarily_ done - as "race" itself is a white supremacist political construct. Say it directly: No questions or answers dealing with "race" are permitted at SE. Instead of arbitrarily deleting content when people get emotionally inflamed by content

Comment: @guest271314 I will be all for defending those users' rights to register their own domain where they can spout whatever nonsense they please. I __don't__ have to defend people trying to co-opt other people's space for their own agenda. That is, unless you don't mind me walking into your house and pushing my agenda on you.

Comment: @JeffLambert Not sure what the issue is with listening to perspectives other than your own? Surely you are so solidly firm in your own beliefs that whatever anyone else says is of no consequence to you, correct? If you become _emotional_ over what someone else says, then the issue may be due to _you_, not the individual expressing their perspective. You do not have to read their questions or answers, no one does. Though, individuals want to _control_ others' expression, both when it is and when it is not their own perspective. Stifling dissent reduces the ability to understand others' position

Comment: @guest271314 If the perspective starts from the presumption that other races are somehow inferior, then I have no problem doing everything in my power to wipe that sort of garbage out wherever I find it. I certainly wouldn't support a law banning such talk out in the woods, or _somewhere else_, because you have a sliver of a point. But you over-extend it and feel that a private entity _owes_ you something which is not the case. Unless that is your pastor wouldn't mind if I spoke next Sunday on the merits of birth control. If you want sympathy for a perspective, start with a better perspective.

Comment: @JeffLambert You are missing the point, see https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3587/21216. The U.S. began with such a proposition. That does not mean that there is not merit in the concept of government that the Founding Fathers put together. The Constitution is an agreement among thieves. The political construct of "race" is a fraud on its face, though the U.S. Census asks individuals what fictitious "race" they self-identify with. Was fortunate enough to not be indoctrinated into any "religion", so, yes, you can speak at any "church" about anything you want to. Set your emotions aside

Comment: @JeffLambert Am not asking for "sympathy". Would contest with facts perhaps much of what the users' might present. That does not mean that they or you should not have the canvas to express their perspective or dissent. We _can_ learn from discourse, if we set emotions aside. As a brief example, learned about SHARP from a Skin Head many years ago. Do not have to agree with all of their politics to still stand for their ability to voice their perspective. What gets lost is _what they want_, which we rarely get to. After the blustering, _class_ issues are generally the  paramount concern.

Comment: @guest271314 I don't have to do any of those things, and if you want me to you have to convince me. I'm not convinced, and I don't think I'm the one missing the point.

Comment: @JeffLambert Am not trying to "convince" you or anyone else of anything. We simply disagree as to the importance of the value of freedom of expression - especially where the expression is that which we might not agree with, or even oppose. Ok, you are not missing the point: Apply the same vehement rationale to the U.S. Census question when that administrative agency asks you what "race" you self-identify with. As the new form might ask to write in some rationale, you would certainly refuse to either check any box or write anything in, as "race" is a white supremacy created political construct.