# Not Rude and Abusive. Why?

Tags: discussion, moderation

After reading [this thread](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3530/rude-and-abusive-why), I flagged this [comment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/32567/who-voted-for-arthur-j-jones-the-neo-nazi-republican-candidate-for-illinoiss-3#comment122704_32567) for moderator attention. As someone who has lived in the state of Illinois, I can assure you that it is not "full of nazis" and take offense that we are being smeared as such. The fact that a fringe candidate won an uncontested primary is no evidence for such a broad sweeping and frankly insulting statement.

As you can see from this [map](https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/624/media/images/72292000/gif/_72292906_us_white_hate_624map.gif), the statement is on its face: false. Despite this being an unsubstantiated, off topic and non productive smear against 12 million people, the flag was declined. So my question is: Are we allowed to label whole groups of people who share nothing more than geography with a slur just because some members of this site want to crack a "joke"? or are there rules here about which groups can be labelled as Nazis and which cannot?

Comment: As someone who currently lives in the state of Illinois, I am surprised that you do not seem to be familiar with the Blue's Brothers and their parody of the [skokie decision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Socialist_Party_of_America_v._Village_of_Skokie)

Comment: You are completely justified in your concern here but I think it's worth pointing out that the map provided doesn't prove what you claim it does.  The number of groups in a state tells us very little how much participation they have.  A state could have a single hate group with a large proportion of the population as members.  Another state could have many groups where the total participation in those groups is very low.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Apologies. I declined your flag by mistake. I must have clicked the wrong button.

I removed the comment now. Unfortunately, I cannot change the status of your flag.